# False positive in probability and stats

Tags: probability

> A cancer test is 90 percent positive when cancer is present. It gives a false positive in 10 percent of the tests when the cancer is not present. If 2 percent of the population has this cancer what is the probability that someone has cancer given that the test is positive?

I multiplied the 90 by 10 divided by 90 times 10 plus 2.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I multiplied the 90 by 10 divided by 90 times 10 plus 2

Comment: I don't have a more accurate attempt yet

Comment: you need to use bayes theorem, A = a person has cancer B = a person tests positive P(A given B) = P(A and B) / P(B) - so then you have to work out P(A and B) and P(B) - that takes a little bit of work - do you know how to do that?

Comment: See the [drug testing example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Drug_testing) of wikipedia’s entry for Bayes’ theorem. This is exactly the same question with slightly different numbers. See also the related questions to the right, for instance [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/900285/265466), which is a duplicate of yours, albeit with different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)?

If not you can get a feeling for it using an "expected average tree diagram".

Imagine 1000 patients.

2% have cancer so you expect to have a split:

- 980 cancer free
- 20 with cancer

Look at the 980 cancer free. We have 10% false positives (test indicates cancer when there is none); so you expect this splits:

- 98 test positive cancer but are cancer free
- 882 test negative for cancer but are cancer free

Look at the 20 with cancer. We have 90% true positives (test indicates cancer when there is cancer); so you expect this splits:

- 18 test positive cancer and have cancer
- 2 test negative for cancer and have cancer

Therefore 98+18=116 test positive for cancer and of these only 18 have cancer.

So the probability of having cancer, given a positive test, is small: $18/116=9/58\approx 15.52\%$.

Bayes Theorem works as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{cancer | positive}]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[\text{cancer and positive}]}{\mathbb{P}[\text{positive}]}.$$

Note 
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\text{positive}]&=\mathbb{P}[\text{(positive | cancer) or (positive | no cancer)}]\\&=\mathbb{P}[\text{positive | cancer}]+\mathbb{P}[\text{positive | no cancer}].
\end{align},$$

and so

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{cancer | positive}]=\frac{0.02(0.9)}{0.02(0.9)+(0.98)(0.1)}=\frac{9}{58}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the event that someone has cancer.

$$P(A)=0.02$$

Let B be the event that the cancer test returns positive. There are four cases to consider:

- Test positive, cancer present: $P(B|A)=0.9$
- Test negative, cancer present: $P(B^c|A)=0.1$
- Test positive, cancer not present: $P(B|A^c)=0.1$
- Test negative, cancer not present: $P(B^c|A^c)=0.9$

The two probabilities are the same here, we will need $P(B|A), P(B|A^c)$, which are given in the question.

We need to find $P(A|B)$.

Bayes' Theorem tells us that:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

and conditional probabilities tell us:

$$\begin{align}
P(B)&=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)\\
&=0.9\times0.02+0.1\times0.98\\
&=0.018+0.098\\
&=0.116
\end{align}
$$

So $P(B|A)=\dfrac{0.018}{0.116}\approx0.15517$.